# Gnuplot - Command Substitution and Script Name

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using Gnuplot as my back-end plotter and I often use the following setup :

```
#Filename : my_plot.gnuplot
set terminal pdfcairo [my_options]
set output 'my_plot.pdf'
....
```

coupled with a Makefile :

```
%.pdf : %.gnuplot
    gnuplot $<
```

My question is simple : is there a command / way to refer to the name of the script inside the script (the equivalent of bash's `$0`) and set the output with a clever `sprintf` or equivalent ?

Comment: This may be a kind of a hack and may work depending on your situation: You can use ! marks to escape gnuplot to enter any Bash commands. So in your case, something like this can work: `! printf "You're running: ``ls *.gp``\n"` Assuming that your gnuplot file extension is .gp and it is in the path. You may be able to change the `ls` command to anything to suite your needs

Comment: Or just simple `! ls *.gp`

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar Nice fix, but the problem is, I'm bound to have dozens of `.gp` file, so I need to be able to refer to the one actually being called :(

Comment: I see, in that case `ls` is not the right thing, how about this `! ps aux | grep gnuplot | awk '{print $12}' | head -n 1` (and you can trim it as needed) instead of `ls`. Although I still wouldn't call this an elegant solution, this makes a lot of assumptions too. I agree a better solution should not go this indirect route.

Comment: Wow, Christoph's answer is definitely shorter and cleaner, but damn, that is a clever one, you should submit it just for the sake of it and I would totally upvote that !

Comment: :) I guess that could get counted as bad SO etiquette, so I'll leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the script name from gnuplot, but you can give a parameter when calling the script, which should work fine, especially when using Makefiles.

```
%.pdf: %.gnuplot
    gnuplot -e "scriptname='$<'" $<
```

In the plot file, this could be used with a command such as:

```
set output scriptname
```

Or from the command line:

```
gnuplot -e "scriptname='my_plot.gnuplot'" my_plot.gnuplot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the script name from gnuplot using the `ARG0` variable.

To try this, just add `show var ARG` to your batch file and load it into gnuplot. This command will output all variables beginning with ARG.

To isolate only the filename (without the path), I'm using this piece of code:

```
start=1; while(1) { pos=strstrt(ARG0[start:], '\') ; if(pos==0) {break;}; start=start+pos; }; scriptname=ARG0[start:]
```

This works on Windows. For Unix/Mac you will have to adapt the path separator.